# SQL Server string to date conversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, formatting

I have the following query:

```
SELECT  o.OrderNumber,
    cast(o.DateOrdered as datetime),
    cast(oi.Category as varchar(max))

 FROM   Orders o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderItems oi ON oi.OrderID = o.uid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderAddresses oa ON oa.OrderID = o.uid

 WHERE O.DateOrdered LIKE '6%2011%' AND (oa.Type = '4') AND (oa.Country = 'US')

 GROUP BY cast(oi.Category as varchar(max)), cast(o.DateOrdered as datetime), o.OrderNumber
```

I'm having trouble formatting the `datetime` as `mm/dd/yyyy`. No matter what I have tried I keep getting like `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00:000`. I must overlooking something simple in the syntax and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?  (SQL Server 2005)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like DateOrdered is VARCHAR

Please try

```
SELECT  o.OrderNumber,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),cast(o.DateOrdered as datetime), 101),
    cast(oi.Category as varchar(max))

 FROM   Orders o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderItems oi ON oi.OrderID = o.uid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderAddresses oa ON oa.OrderID = o.uid

 WHERE O.DateOrdered LIKE '6%2011%' AND (oa.Type = '4') AND (oa.Country = 'US')

 GROUP BY cast(oi.Category as varchar(max)), CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),cast(o.DateOrdered as datetime), 101), o.OrderNumber
```

Comment: Thank you EricZ!  I don't work in SQL much and knew I was completely overlooking something like that.  once I wrapped the cast in the convert per your example it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try `CONVERT` instead of `CAST`:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), o.DateOrdered , 101)
```

So the GROUP BY statement would look like:

```
GROUP BY CAST(oi.Category as varchar(MAX)), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), o.DateOrdered , 101), o.OrderNumber
```

Comment: When I tried this earlier (and again here just to be sure) I end up getting my date format without zeros in the day.  For instance, i get 6/1/2011 instead of 6/01/2011 so it the ordering is off.  Tried adjusting through the various format specificiations (101, 102, etc...) and the query returned the same results.  Any ideas?  The string field I am getting the date our of is a nvarchar(50) if that could have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Scott: I see 0's in the month and date fields am not sure what could be the problem.. Try this instead: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), o.DateOrdered , 112)`

Comment: That change doesn't effect the result set, still get dates without leading zeros.  I tested GETDATE(), in the same format just to be sure it wasn't SQL server related.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

`CAST` will only convert data types - but it doesn't give you the ability to choose any formatting.

For formatting, you'll need to use `CONVERT` instead (see [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for details):

Try

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 101)
```

which should render the current date in the format you're looking for.